# pygraphviz installation error in Google Colab

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory, graphviz, pygraphviz

Installing Pygraphviz on Google Colab using pip
`**pip install pygraphviz**` gives the following error:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pygraphviz
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for pygraphviz (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygraphviz
  Running setup.py clean for pygraphviz
Failed to build pygraphviz
Installing collected packages: pygraphviz
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Running setup.py install for pygraphviz did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Running setup.py install for pygraphviz ... error
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> pygraphviz

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
```

The command used should ideally work, however installation of pygraphviz fails by throwing the error "**python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully**"

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install pygraphviz in Google Colab by running the following commands:

```
!apt install libgraphviz-dev
!pip install pygraphviz
```

An Explanation for this from anyone is much appreciated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).